# Reference: Embedding of Exceptional Lie Algebras in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for a reference that explains in some detail how to embed exceptional Lie algebras ($\mathfrak{g}_2, \mathfrak{f}_4, \mathfrak{e}_6, \mathfrak{e}_7,$ and $\mathfrak{e}_8$) in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ (especially the relation between roots of the exceptional Lie algebras and $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ under embeddings) and whether such embeddings are possible at all.

Comment: I assume you mean the compact real forms of those Lie algebras here. How much representation theory of such compact forms via their complexification, highest weights etc., do you already know? (And does the representation theory of classical Lie algebras give you much hope that something like $\mathfrak{so}_9 \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{su}(16)$ gives a strong relation between the root systems $B_4$ and $A_{15}$?)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I returned to this problem after quite a while, not sure whether you still check the comment. I know how to embed $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ and $\mathfrak{sp}(n)$ in $\mathfrak{su}(2n)$. I just want to know the same for the exceptional Lie algebras, or as you pointed out the compact forms thereof. I am not sure about the embedding you pointed out. Only a reference would be enough. I assume these are very well-known facts.